# What the meaning of !cin in c++?

Tags: c++

I read a c++ book and it shows this code,

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{   
    int total, choice;
    std::cin >> total >> choice;
    if (!std::cin) //bad input
    {
        std::cout <<total << choice;
    }
}
```

Actually, I don't know what is good input and bad input because no matter what I input, it still cannot cout, so how to output a 'good' input?

Comment: The code does not have the good path. `if (!cin)` means something went wrong with parsing the input to the 2 integers. So, if you enter `15 abc` it should print `15 <some garbage value>`. https://godbolt.org/z/Kj3TKPzPn

Comment: Have you tried inputting text, not numbers?

Answer (score 2):

!cin checks is [fail()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) returns true for the stream. Before c++11 this was going through void*, after that it is using bool operator as indicated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). What fail checks is if `failbit` or `badbit` are up for the stream and you can read more about them [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).